# Why doesn't Sodium (Na) form duplet?

Tags: bond, electronic-configuration, metal, stability, elements

The atomic number of Na is 11 (2, 8, 1). Na loses an electron to achieve octet stability but why can't it just accept an electron to complete duplet stability?

Comment: Why, [of course it can](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkalide). The problem is, there are not enough free electrons for everyone.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin Would you elaborate "there are not enough free electrons for everyone. "?

Comment: I mean, all $\ce{Na}$ can't convert to $\ce{Na-}$. But I guess that's not what the question was about, anyway.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Thanks :). Please elaborate on "there are not enough free electrons" and turn it into an answer; I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I think the stability and having a stronger reducer than Na is going  to be an issue forming Na-.

Comment: Crystalline compounds of sodium anion with polycyclic ether cage like compounds are known. (According to Wikipedia  see Dye et al. J. Am. Chem. Soc. 1974, v96, p608)

Comment: [related](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/32686/1573) or, more likely, a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have a diatomic molecule of sodium in gaseous state?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32686/is-it-possible-to-have-a-diatomic-molecule-of-sodium-in-gaseous-state)

Comment: @bobthechemist The questions are completely different even though they might have a similar answer. It is absolutely not the same asking "Why doesn't it accept an electron?" and "Does a dimer exist?"

Comment: @Martin-マーチンI agree.  Rereading the question, I see that I misunderstood that the OP is asking about atomic electron configurations.

Comment: Explanation: The sodium cannot just accept an electron and continue its duplet stability because that duplet stability only applies to the Helium. However, an atom can tend to make itself a duplet atom, like Lithium, which has 3 electrons and loses its 1 electron and becomes a duplet atom. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, sodium does have [non-zero electron affinity](http://periodictable.com/Properties/A/ElectronAffinity.v.log.html), so it surely can acquire another electron, provided it can get one for free. That's what happens when a lone sodium atom meets a lone electron somewhere in deep space. But here on Earth, with all that condensed matter around, we don't have many free electrons (*). They all belong to some other atoms, and if you want to get an electron (that is, to get reduced), you have to oxidize something else.

---

(*) Then again, some might recall **metals** in which the electrons are kinda free, but wait: they are not really free. They are bound by the collective field of metal cations, and you need to apply [certain energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function) to take one out.

---

It turns out that $\ce{Na}$ and other alkali metals **can** actually be reduced to form [alkalides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkalide), but those are exotic compounds. They are not particularly stable, and get oxidized with pretty much *anything*. It is much easier for $\ce{Na}$ to form a cation, thus achieving the stable octet, and call it a day.

There is a whole different dimension to the problem: why wouldn't *two* sodium atoms share their electrons, establish a bond, and form a diatomic molecule? Again, they would, but only in a vacuum! When you have *many* such molecules, the sodium atoms would share their other empty orbitals, find out they don't have enough electrons to fill them all, and just resort to being a metal.

Comment: Yes, I believe the species $\ce{Na2}$ (and other such diatomic alkali metals) have been observed in the gas phase, as is predicted by qualitative MO diagrams.

Comment: Related: [Why are lithides not known?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/73686/why-are-lithides-not-known)

Comment: Published a little after all the above: Hyperfine structure of alkali-metal diatomic molecules J. Aldegunde, J. M. Hutson  https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.05734

Answer (score 2):

Sodium not only forms species with two electrons in the $3s$ subshell ($\ce{Na^-,Na2}$). It is also known to form a *dimer* of the $\ce{Na^-}$ion, even though the individual atoms therein possess closed-shell electronic structures and would not be expected to form a covalent bonds to offset the repulsion between the negative charges.

The dimeric $\ce{Na_2^{2-}}$ anion occurs in **barium azacryptand sodide** [[1]](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja027241m). The crystal structure, pictured as shown below from [1], features the large, blue atoms which are the paired sodium atoms in this dianion (red atoms are barium, the small green atoms are from the cryptand). The large atomic size, corresponding to a highly diffuse electron cloud, reduces the like-charge repulsion while improving polarizability for a VdW attraction.

[image]

**Reference**

1.
Mikhail Y. Redko, Rui H. Huang, James E. Jackson, James F. Harrison, and James L. Dye, "Barium Azacryptand Sodide, the First Alkalide with an Alkaline Earth Cation, Also Contains a Novel Dimer, (Na2)2-", *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* 2003, **125**, 8, 2259–2263. https://doi.org/10.1021/ja027241m